# What is 人 doing in 你现在人在哪里？

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-structure

I got this sentence in my "daily exercise" newsletter, and I really don't understand what's 人 doing there? Doesn't it mean the same when 人 is removed? Could this simply be a typo?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both sentences are correct. The word "人" is added to add emphasis to the **physical** location of the person.

You can take `你现在在哪里？` to mean "Where are you now?"

And `你现在人在哪里？` to mean "What is your current physical location?"

The former is normally used when the asker and the subject are within the same locality (e.g in a shopping mall). The latter is often used when the asker and the subject are far away from each other (e.g. in different countries).

A corresponding response to `你现在在哪里？` is `我现在在XX。`

A corresponding response to `你现在人在哪里？` is `我现在人在XX。`

Comment: This may be a stupid question, but how are the answers to those questions different? Aren't they both asking about physical location?

Comment: @drHannibalLecter, I have updated my answer to clarify the usage. Please take a look.

Comment: I believe in english you could also say "where is your person"? But sounds very formal. In on-flight safety videos they use instruct passengers "remove sharp objects from your person" in case of emergency landing.

Comment: In English, it's more natural to explicitly specify the location - "Where are you in the mall?" or "Where are you in the carpark?"

Comment: @drHannibalLecter 张三：“你在哪儿？”李四：“我在freenode.net的#ruby频道。”张三：“你人在哪儿？”李四：“在北京。”

Answer (score 5):

Actually, 你现在人在哪里, is more like "where the hell are you now?" but maybe not that strong.  I personally will use that sentence if I were kept waiting and had to call someone to ask where he/she is.

Answer (score 3):

正确的解析应该是有点埋怨的意思，例如我跟你约会，你迟到，我有点生气打电话：：“你现在人在哪里！”

---

A proper analysis should have a bit of a reproachful feeling. For example, if you are late arriving for our date, I might make an angry phone call: “你现在人在哪里！”

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thanks for your answer. Answering in Chinese is OK, but try to add a small English translation if you can, especially if the question was in English.

Answer (score 1):

你现在人在哪里？ refers to the *physical* person, as opposed to "where are you" (intellectually)?

The 人character also separates the two 在s

Comment: Oh, so "你现在在哪里？" can be used to mean "where are you [intellectually]"? Is it in the sense of "what are you thinking about right now" or "what do you think now [about that issue we talked about earlier]"? I'm guessing the latter..?

Comment: That's my understanding, although it isn't often used that way.

Comment: Also, is it necessary to separate the two 在s? Or is it just something which makes you sound more natural or "more native"?

Comment: I'd say it sounds more natural. It's helpful but not mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

Understanding the following sentences may help you resolve your confusion.

> 你的人在哪里？

It can be parsed like

你的 人 在哪里？

It just like

你的 手机 在哪里?

你的 脑袋 在哪里？

你的 注意力(attention) 在哪里？

你的 精神(like ego in boost one's ego) 在哪里？

> 你的现在的人在哪里？

你的 现在的 人 在哪里？

> 你(的)现在(的)人在哪里

or

> 现在，你的人在哪里

现在，你的 人 在哪里

skimming redundant yields

> 现在，你 人 在哪里

interchange the order of "现在" and "你" to emphasize the latter.

> 你[现在] 人 在哪里